# Stable and causal system

Tags: linear-systems, magnitude, causality

How many stable and causal systems with the same magnitude response are there?

I know this relates to an all pass system for two rational transfer functions but am not sure about the specifics of this

Comment: Wouldn't stability and causality be conserved when adding any delay?

Comment: This question appears to be homework. Complete answers to homework are off-topic, but specific questions about homework are acceptable if they include enough detail. Please edit the question to include more background about what you don't understand.

Comment: there are infinite number of stable and causal LTI systems with the same magnitude response.